# How may I prove this inequality?

Tags: inequality

Let $a, b, c$ be positive real, $abc = 1$. Prove that:

$$\frac{1}{1+a+b} + \frac{1}{1+b+c} + \frac{1}{1+c+a} \le \frac{1}{2+a} + \frac{1}{2+b}+\frac{1}{2+c}$$

I thought of Cauchy and AM-GM, but I don't see how to successfully use them to prove the inequality. Any hint, suggestion will be welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$p=a+b+c$ and $q=ab+bc+ca$. Using $AM-GM$ we obtain that : $p,q \geq 3.$
The inequality is equivalent with:

$$\dfrac{3+4p+q+p^2}{2p+q+p^2+pq} \leq \dfrac{12+4p+q}{9+4p+2q} \Leftrightarrow$$
$$3p^2q+pq^2+6pq-5p^2-q^2-24p-3q-27 \geq 0 \Leftrightarrow \\\left(3p^2q-5p^2-12p\right)+\left(pq^2-q^2-3p-3q\right)+\left(6pq-9p-27\right) \geq 0.$$

Comment: wow! Very nice!

Comment: Just to point out a typo: The $y$ in the second parenthetic term should be a $q$.

Comment: Someone calls this method "uvw" downloadable here http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?f=52&t=492392&p=2761292&hilit=uvw#p2761292

Comment: @Unoqualunque: I didn't know that. Interesting! Thanks +1

Answer (score 2):

$\frac{2}{1+a+b}-(\frac{1}{2+a}+\frac{1}{2+b})$

$=\frac{1}{1+a+b}-\frac{1}{2+a}+\frac{1}{1+a+b}-\frac{1}{2+b}$

$=\frac{1}{1+a+b}(\frac{1-b}{2+a}+\frac{1-a}{2+b})$

$=\frac{1}{(1+a+b)(2+a)(2+b)}((1-b)(2+b)+(1-a)(2+a))$

$≤\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 2}(4-(a+b+a^2+b^2))$ as $a,b>0,2+a>2$ and $a+b+1>1$

$\sum(\frac{2}{1+a+b}-(\frac{1}{2+a}+\frac{1}{2+b}))≤\frac{1}{4}(3\cdot 4-2(a+b+c)-2(a^2+b^2+c^2))≤0$ as $a^n+b^n+c^n≥3(abc)^{\frac{n}{3}}=3$ for any positive number $n$.

$\implies \sum2(\frac{1}{1+a+b})≤ \sum2(\frac{1}{2+a})$

Comment: Can anybody please verify the following: as $\sum (4-(a^2+b^2+a+b))<0$ at least one of $4-(a^2+b^2+a+b)$ must be $<0$.  In that case, does $\frac{1}{(1+a+b)(2+a)(2+b)}((1-b)(2+b)+(1-a)(2+a))≤\frac{1}{1\cdot 2\cdot 2}(4-(a+b+a^2+b^2))$ hold as the numerator $<0$ and denominator is decreased? Like, $-\frac{4}{9}<-\frac{4}{7}?$

Comment: I think you blocked me to edit the questions because I want to improve your post putting "\displaystyle" before the equations.

Comment: Could you please let me know how to block or unblock?